# can't connect 2 subnets through RRAS 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ping, vmware-workstation, nic, rras

I'm working on a project for a networking class. In VMWare Workstation, I have to set up a 2008 r2 server with DHCP reservations for 2 clients on separate subnets and have them ping each other.

Here is the output of the route print command:

```
===========================================================================

Interface List

 13 ...00 50 56 2a e7 11 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #3

 10 ...00 0c 29 66 88 dd ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection

  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1

 24 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter

 11 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

 14 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter

 16 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2

 17 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{5B8FB196-616F-4168-A020-03E63A309CEC}

===========================================================================



IPv4 Route Table

===========================================================================

Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

         10.0.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

        128.6.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2     11

    128.6.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

        223.6.6.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.2     11

        223.6.6.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

        223.6.6.2  255.255.255.255         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

      223.6.6.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

      223.6.6.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         223.6.6.2    266

===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:

  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.2  Default

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        128.6.0.2  Default

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        223.6.6.2  Default

        128.6.0.0      255.255.0.0         10.0.0.2       1

        223.6.6.0    255.255.255.0         10.0.0.2       1

===========================================================================



IPv6 Route Table

===========================================================================

Active Routes:

 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway

  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link

 14   1010 2002::/16                On-link

 14    266 2002:8006:2::8006:2/128  On-link

  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link

===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:

  None
```

My problem is that although I have set up both dynamic and persistent static routes in my r2 server, neither of the clients can ping even the NIC outside its own subnet. For example Client A can ping the NIC at 10.0.0.2 and vice-versa, but it gets a general transmit failure when it tries to ping the card at 223.6.6.2, let alone trying to ping the other client.

I have completely disabled the firewalls on all machines and anything else I could think of, without success. What am I missing?

Edit: Since posting this, I also noticed that the default gateways on my 2 NICs keep getting zeroed out. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can only set one default gateway per machine. if you want to route out traffic on nic 2 to another network you had to set static routes for this networks. so just set a DG eihter on nic 1 or nic 2 and to the rest with static routes